# My program gives an Unhandled exception error whenever I try to initialize a Employer object

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I tried to initialize the the Employer object using the emp2 pointer but I keep getting an error :

> Unhandled exception at 0x008d2c6b in empPract.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0xcdcdcde5.

I tried finding the error by stepping through the code and looking up the error code online. How can I identify and correct the problem?

Here's the code:

Main Driver:

```
#include "Employer.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void main(){
    Employer *emp2;
    emp2=new Employer();// this is where i tried to initialize the employer 

    cout <<"Employer id:" << emp2->getUniqueId() << endl;
    system("PAUSE");


}// end main
```

Employer class:

```
#ifndef EMPLOYER_H
#define EMPLOYER_H
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "JobSeeker.h"
#include <string>
#include "Address.h"
//#define MAX 1000;
using namespace std;


class Employer{
private:
    int empID;
    string companyName; // addresss of the company
    Address *empAddress;
    string compTelephone;
    string areaOfEmployment;
    //Person *manager;
    string contactName;
    string contactTitle;
    int maxRecruits; // number of employees needed
    int totalRecruited;
    int totalPlaced;
    // links
    Employer *next;
public:
    Employer(){
        empID=0;
        companyName=" ";
        compTelephone=" ";
        areaOfEmployment=" ";
        contactName=" ";
        contactTitle=" ";
        maxRecruits=0;
        totalRecruited=0;
        totalPlaced=0;
        empAddress->setStreet(" ");
        empAddress->setStreetNum(" ");
        empAddress->setParish(" ");
        // set links
        next=NULL;
    }// default constructor


    Employer(int id, string cname, Address *usrAdd, string telephone, string nameOfContact, string contTitle,  string aoe ){
        empID=id;
        companyName=cname;
        compTelephone= telephone;
        contactName=nameOfContact;
        contactTitle=contTitle;
        areaOfEmployment=aoe;
        empAddress->setStreet(usrAdd->getStreet());
        empAddress->setStreetNum(usrAdd->getStreetNum());
        empAddress->setParish(usrAdd->getParish());
        // set links
        next=NULL;
    }// Primary Constructor */

    //copy constructor
    Employer(Employer *emp1){
        empID=emp1->getUniqueId();
        companyName=emp1->getCompanyName();
        compTelephone=emp1->getCompTelephone();
        contactName=emp1->getContactName();
        contactTitle=emp1->getContactTitle();
        areaOfEmployment=emp1->getAOE();        
        empAddress=emp1->getAddress();
        next=NULL;
    }// copy constructor


    //destructor
    Employer::~Employer(){
        delete empAddress;
        delete next;
    }// destructor

    void setEmpID(){
       // srand(5);
       // EmpID = rand()%MAX+1;
    }// set id

    int getUniqueId(){
        return empID;
    }// end of getter for EmpID 

    void setCompanyName(string cname){
        companyName=cname;
    }// end of setter for company name

    string getCompanyName(){
        return companyName;
    }// end of function to return companyName

    void setCompTelephone(string cTele){
        compTelephone=cTele;
    }// end of setter for company's telephone number

    string getCompTelephone(){
        return compTelephone;
    }// end of getter for company telephone number

    void setContactName(string cName){
        contactName=cName;
    }// end of setContactName

    string getContactName(){
        return contactName;
    }// end of getter  for contactName

    void setContactTitle(string title){
        contactTitle=title;
    }// end of setter for contactTitle

    string getContactTitle(){
        return contactTitle;
    }// end of getter for contactTitle

    void setMaxRecruits(int max){
        maxRecruits=max;
    }   // end of setter for maxRecruits



    int getMaxRecruits(){
        return maxRecruits;
    }// end of getter for maxRecruits

    void setAreaOfEmployment( string aoe){
        areaOfEmployment=aoe;
    }// end of setter for aoe

    string getAOE(){
        return areaOfEmployment;
    }// end of getter for areaOfEmployment

    // set links
    void setNext(Employer *nx){
        next=nx;
    }// end  mutator for setNexEmp


    void setAddress(string street, string streetNumber, string par){
        empAddress->setStreet(street);
        empAddress->setStreetNum(streetNumber);
        empAddress->setParish(par);
    }// end of setter for employer address

    Address * getAddress(){
        return empAddress;
    }// end of getter for address

    // set links
    Employer *getNext(){
        return next;
    }// end of getter for nextEmployer

};
#endif
```

JobSeeker class:

```
  #ifndef JOBSEEKER_H
#define JOBSEEKER_H
#include <string>
#include "Address.h"
#include "Person.h"
#include <time.h>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

class JobSeeker:public Person{
private:
    string middlename;
    string gender;
    string TRN;
    string NIS;
    Person *reference[2];
    Date *dob;
    string AreaOfInt;
    string recruitmentStatus;
    string companyPlaced;
    time_t lastSelectedDate; //  date the JobSeeker was last recruited/ placed
    time_t dateOfRegistration; // date the job seekeer registered
    Address *jSeekerAddress;

    // links
    JobSeeker *next;
public:

    JobSeeker(){
        int i;
        next=NULL;
        dob=NULL;
        middlename="";
        firstname="";
        lastname="";
        TRN="";
        NIS="";
        gender="";
        wrkNum="";
        cellNum="";
        homeNum="";
        for (i=0; i<2;i++){
            reference[i]->setFirstName("");
            reference[i]->setLastname("");
            reference[i]->setCellNum("");
            reference[i]->setHomeNum("");
            reference[i]->setWrkNum("");
            Address *temp=new Address();
            reference[i]->setAddress(temp);
        }// end for loop
        AreaOfInt="";        
        recruitmentStatus="";
        companyPlaced="";
        lastSelectedDate=time(0); // last selected date for job seeker
        dateOfRegistration=time(0); // date the job seeker registered
        jSeekerAddress->setStreet("");
        jSeekerAddress->setStreetNum("");
        jSeekerAddress->setParish("");
    }// end of default constructor for job seeker


    JobSeeker(JobSeeker *js){
        int i;
        firstname= js->getFirstname();
        middlename=js->getMiddlename();
        lastname=js->getLastname();
        dob=js->getDOB();
        TRN=js->getUniqueId();
        NIS=js->getNIS();
        gender=js->getGender();
        wrkNum=js->getWrkNum();
        cellNum= js->getCellNum();
        homeNum=js->getHomeNum();

        reference[i]= js->getReference1();
        reference[i]=js->getReference2();
            //reference[i]->

        lastSelectedDate=js->getSelectedDate();
        dateOfRegistration=js->getDateOFReg();
        AreaOfInt=js->getAreaOFInt();
        recruitmentStatus=js->getRecruitStatus();
        companyPlaced=js->getCompanyPlaced();

        // set link to next jobseeker
        next=js->getNext();

    }// copy constructor

    // destructor
    JobSeeker::~JobSeeker(){
        delete next;
        delete dob;
        delete reference[0]; reference[1];
        delete jSeekerAddress;
    }// destructor

    void setMiddlename(string mname){
        middlename=mname;
    }// end of setter for middlename

    string getMiddlename(){
        return middlename;
    }// end of getter for middlename

    void setTRN(string usrTRN){
        TRN=usrTRN;
    }// end setter for TRN

    string getUniqueId(){
        return TRN;
    }// end of getter for TRN

    void setNIS(string usrNIS){
        NIS=usrNIS;
    }// end setter for NIS

    string getNIS(){
        return NIS;
    }// end of getter for NIS

    void setGender(char g){
        gender = g;
    }// end of gender setter

    string getGender(){
        return gender;
    }// end of getter for gender



    void setAreaOFInterest(string aoi){
        AreaOfInt=aoi;
    }// end of setter for AreaOfInt

    string getAreaOFInt(){
        return AreaOfInt;
    }// end of getter for AreaOfInt


    void setDOB(int d, int m, int y){
        dob->setDay(d);
        dob->setbMonth(m);
        dob->setYear(y);
    }// setter for date of birth of person

    Date* getDOB(){
        return dob;
    }// end of getter for DOB


    void addReference(Person *p, int numOfRef){
        int count=0;
        while(count <= numOfRef){
            reference[count]->setFirstName(p->getFirstname());
            reference[count]->setLastname(p->getLastname());
            reference[count]->setCellNum(p->getCellNum());
            reference[count]->setWrkNum(p->getWrkNum());
            reference[count]->setHomeNum(p->getHomeNum());
            //Address ad= p.getAddress();
            reference[count]->setAddress(p->getStreetName() ,p->getStreetNum(),p->getParish());
            //reference[count]->setAddress(p->getAddress());
        }
     }// end of loop to add reference
    Person* getReference1(){
        return reference[0];
    }// end of getter for reference1

    Person* getReference2(){
        return reference[1];
    }// end of getter for reference2

    // method to set the registration date
    void setDateOFReg(){
        dateOfRegistration=time(0); // sets the date to the computer's date
    }// end of method to set registration date

    void setCompanyPlaced(string company){
        companyPlaced=company;
    }// end of setter for companyPlaced

    string getCompanyPlaced(){
        return companyPlaced;
    }// end of accessor for comp placed

    void setRecruitStatus(string status){
        recruitmentStatus=status;
    }// setter for recruitment status

    string getRecruitStatus(){
        return recruitmentStatus;
    }// end of accessor for recruitment status



        // method to get the registration date
    time_t getDateOFReg(){
        return dateOfRegistration;
        /* Hubert please remember that the date is not formatted. to do so:
          you must use 'ctime(&variableName)' with cout or gui
          and remembe to include 'time.h' */
    }// end of getter for registration date


    void setDateSelected(){
        lastSelectedDate=time(0); // this sets the time to the cuurrent date
    }// sets last selected date to current date

    time_t getSelectedDate(){
        return lastSelectedDate; // remember needs formatting like registration date too
    }// returns the last selected date



    // set links (pointer)
    void setNext(JobSeeker *n){
        next=n;
    }// end of setNext

    JobSeeker * getNext(){
        return next;
    }// end of getNext

};// end class
#endif // end of Job Seeker class
```

Person class:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include "Address.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person{
protected:
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    Address *personAddress;
    string wrkNum;
    string cellNum;
    string homeNum;
    //Person *persPointer;


public:
    Person(){
        firstname= "default";
        lastname="default";
        wrkNum="";
        cellNum="";
        homeNum="";
        personAddress->setStreet("");
        personAddress->setStreetNum(0);
        personAddress->setParish("blank");
    }// default constructor for person

    //Address *personAddress;
    void setFirstName(string fname){
        firstname=fname;
    }// end of firstname setter

    void setLastname(string lname){
        lastname=lname;
    }// end of lastname setter

    string getFirstname(){
        return firstname;
    }// end of getter for firstname

    string getLastname(){
        return lastname;
    }// end of getter for lastname


    void setWrkNum(string tNum){
       wrkNum=tNum;
    }// end of method to set home number

    string getWrkNum(){
        return wrkNum;
    }// end of getter for  telNum

    void setCellNum(string cNum){
        cellNum=cNum;
    }// end of setter for cellNum

    string getCellNum(){
        return cellNum;
    }// end of getter for cellNum

    void setHomeNum(string hNum){
        homeNum=hNum;
    }// setter for home number

    string getHomeNum(){
        return homeNum;
    }// getter for homeNum

    void setAddress(string streetName, string streetNum, string parish){
        personAddress->setStreet(streetName);
        personAddress->setStreetNum(streetNum);
        personAddress->setParish(parish);
    }// end of address setter

    void setAddress(Address *ad){
        personAddress->setStreet(ad->getStreet());
        personAddress->setStreetNum(ad->getStreetNum());
        personAddress->setParish(ad->getParish());
    }

    Address* getAddress(){
        return personAddress;
    }// get personAddress


    string getStreetName(){
        return personAddress->getStreet();
    }// end of method to get Street name

     string getStreetNum(){
        return personAddress->getStreetNum();
    }// end of method to get streetNum

     string getParish(){
        return personAddress->getParish();          ;
    }// end of getter for parish


};// end of class Person

#endif // PERSON_H
```

Date class:

```
#ifndef Date_H
#define Date_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date{
private:
    int day, month, year;
public:
    Date(){
        day= 0;
        month=0;
        year=0;
    }// end of DOB default constructor


    void setDay(int d){
        day=d;
    }// end of setter for bDay

    // setbMonth
    void setbMonth(int m){
        month= m;
    }// end of setter for bMonth

    void setYear(int y){
        year=y;
    }// end of setter for year

    // display method
    void display(){
        cout << month << "/ " << day <<"/ " << year << endl;
    }// end diplay method for date
}; // emd of class DOB

#endif // Date_H
```

Address class:

```
// class used for the addresses of the employees and the job seekers
// Date created Feb 28, 2012
#ifndef ADDRESS_H
#define ADDRESS_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Address{
private:
    string streetName;
    string streetNum;
    string parish;

public:
    Address(){
        streetName= "unknown";
        streetNum="";
        parish="blank";
    }// end of default constructor for Address

    // destructor for address
    Address::~Address(){
    }// end of destructor

    void setStreet(string street){
        streetName=street;
    }// end of setter for street name

    void setStreetNum(string streetNumber){
        streetNum=streetNumber;
    }// end of setter streetNumber

    void setParish(string par){
        parish=par;
    }// end of setter for parish

    //getters

    string getStreet(){
        return streetName;
    }//end of getter for street

    string getStreetNum(){
        return streetNum;
    }// end of getter for streetNum

    string getParish(){
        return parish;
    }// end of getter for



};// end of class Address
#endif
```

Comment: First, you need to narrow it down to a *minimal* piece of code that demonstrates the problem. Second, read up on [pseudo-OO and quasi-clases](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what i can see empAddress member in Employer class is a pointer and never initialised. In you employer contructor you try to access it

```
empAddress->setStreet(" ");
    empAddress->setStreetNum(" ");
    empAddress->setParish(" ");
```

Thus creating a memory violation error, because empAddress must contain garbage. A good pratice it to always set pointers to NULL, so if you crash you see a NULL value not some random value.

So create empAddress in contructor `this->empAddress= new Address()`

Another good pratice (matching the one i gave you): If your unused pointer or freed pointer are set to NULL, you can easily test them to see if you can use them or free them.
For example in your employer destructor, you delete empAddress without any prior testing, that can cause error if you made a mistake somewhere else in you code.
In your case if you didn't crash in contructor, you would have crashed in destructor.

Comment: this really works! wow i couldn't even see that, from now on i'll always initialize pointers to NULL .

Comment: Ok, but don't forget to create you object if you use pointers =) (and also to free it when not needed anymore)

Comment: You also have a problem in your copy contructor with `empAddress=emp1->getAddress();`. This will work, but you will have two Employer object having their AddressObject pointer pointing to the same object. Imagine you do `Employer A = new Employer(); Employer B = new Employer(&A); delete A;` The B object will have an address pointer linking freed memory, that will cause in the worst case a memory access violation. So in copy contructor, COPY everything. Also prefer to use reference to pass object in copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `empAddress->setStreet(" ");` in the default constructor, but empAddress is not initialized.